# Curly underline for SpellBad

Tags: vim

I am sort of new to vim, and I have a simple question:

I'm using vim for editing .tex documents and I am using spell checker (spell). The problem is that when cursorline is enabled I can't see the SpellBad highlighting for that line, is there any way to change the SpellBad highlighting to, for example, a red curly underline (or just make the highlighting appear when cursorline is enabled)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GVIM, the curly underlining is the default for spelling errors, so I guess you're concerned about terminal Vim.

Terminals only support a limited number of attributes; usually colors, underline, many also bold, but **not** curly underlining. To work with the *cursorline*, you need to choose a differing attribute; i.e. when you use a different background color for the cursorline, you cannot indicate spell errors via a background color, but may choose underlining.

You can modify the colors (after any `:colorscheme` command) in your `~/.vimrc`, like this:

```
:hi SpellBad cterm=underline
```

See `:help :hi` for details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you color the underline or make it bolder?

Comment: You'd have to choose a different font in your terminal emulator. The color cannot be set differently, AFAIK; the terminal stuff is 1960's technology :-)

Comment: Ok :p. But when i do searches the highlighting is still present when i hold the cursor on the same line (i.e. the cursorline option does not hide the highlighting) how can i recreate that type of effect for my SpellBad?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. The Search highlighting is hard-coded to have higher priority than the cursorline. I wish it were different, and had raised this once: http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/46c70a229488de20

Comment: Uhhh, that sucks. If i understand you correctly the priority is: search-highlighting > cursorline highlighting > custom highlighting (ex. hi SpellBad)? Isn't there some plugin out there that creates a custom cursorhighlighting with low priority?

Comment: You're right. There used to be plugins, but their problems (with updating and speed) caused the inclusion of 'cursorline'. I'm still in favor of an option to configure the priority, but without a patch submittal from someone, nothing will change.

Comment: (5 years later) Some terminal emulators, e.g. Kitty and VTE (gnome-terminal and others) added support for curly underline, and also a different color for the underline than for the text. See https://askubuntu.com/a/985386.